# replace js with square brackets

Tags: javascript

I'm hoping there is a better way to write this? Removing [] square brackets are a problem to me.

```
alert(CanvasData)//images[]=Base.jpg&images[]=Frame_Clear.png&images[]=Left_Clear.png&images[]=Right_Clear.png&images[]=Lenses_Lenses-Semi-Clear.png&images[]=


var PayName = CanvasData.replace("images[]=", "");
PayName = PayName.replace(/\[.*?\]/g, '');
PayName = PayName.replace(/\&images=/g, ' ');
PayName = PayName.replace(/\.png/g, " &");
PayName = PayName.replace(/\_/g, ' ');
PayName = PayName.substring(8);//remove fist 8 character (Base.jpg)
PayName = PayName.substring(0, PayName.length - 2);//remove last 2 characters // Frame Clear & Left Clear & Right Clear & Lenses Lenses-Semi-Clear &


alert(PayName)// Frame Clear & Left Clear & Right Clear & Lenses Lenses-Semi-Clear
```

Thanks

Comment: You should use `console.log()` instead of `alert()` for debugging purposes - and check for the output in your browser's JavaScript console.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Just make all the square brackets disappear? Please make that clear. Tell us outside the code itself - we can't judge what you're trying to do just by your code. Consider the possibility that your code might contain a huge bug and be doing stuff you don't intend: would you rather be told how to achieve your goal (and that there's a bug in your code), or a better way to perform this hugely undesirable behaviour?

Comment: This sounds like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You will get better answer if you tell what exactly do you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call replace with three global regular expressions, where the first call lists every alternate that should be replaced with nothing (i.e. remove all '=', and 'Base.jpg&'), the second lists alternates that should be replaced with a space ('images[]', '_', and '.png'), and the third ties up your loose ends:

```
 var PayName = CanvasData.replace(/=|Base\.jpg&/g,'')
                         .replace(/images\[\]|_|\.png/g, ' ')
                         .replace(/^\s*|\s*&\s*$/g, '');

 // => "Frame Clear & Left Clear & Right Clear & Lenses Lenses-Semi-Clear"
```

Answer (score 1):

try escaping the brackets, otherwise they take on a special meaning (define a character class) for the regular expression.

```
CanvasData.replace("images\[\]=", "");
```

You are already doing the same thing, by the way, in the second line of code in the replace section.

Answer (score 0):

If the square brackets `[]` are always empty, you could do:

`var Payname = CanvasData.split("[]").join("");`

Obviously that doesn't handle the general case.

What this does, is treat `[]` as a data separator, and turn the string into a parsed array -- just like parsing "1,3,6,4.5,3" except our comma is a `[]`. Then the array formed by breaking up the string is joined back to a string, with a blank separator. All the `[]` disappear.  But those `[occupied]` do not.